# ActionItem shows error

Tags: android, quickaction

I am a complete newbie on Android.

I am trying the quickaction code. I followed  http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/    and
  https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D   and @Qberticus code on stackoverflow.

But I am stuck up at the basic step.
The ActionItem is not working in my code.

I know I am going wrong somewhere but cant get where.!
Exactly where should I place this code?
Is it bcoz I havent used ActionBar or something else?

Many Thanks. :)

[Here is the code snapshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijujE.png)

Comment: Please guide me through this,friends... I am really confused and want to know what have I done wrong.

Comment: Did you add NewQuickAction3D as a library in your project?

Comment: yup i took the zip file from github and added imported it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have an alternative. Use dropdown menu if it helps in your application. and all u hv to do is import the quickaction library. Try if it helps.